# Find the pgf given distribution of X

Tags: probability-theory

If $X\sim geom(p)$ then the pmf of $X$ is given by:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{gathered}
\begin{aligned}
    p_{X}(k)&=p(1-p)^{k-1}, & k=1,2,...\\
    &=p(1-p)^{k}, & k=0,1,2,...\\
\end{aligned}
\end{gathered}
\end{equation*}

Then by the definition of the pgf of $X$ and that $s\in[0,1]$ and $p\in[0,1]$:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
    G_{X}(s)=E(s^{X})&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}s^{k}p_{X}(k)\\
    &=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}s^{k}p(1-p)^{k}\\
    &=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}p(s-ps)^{k}\\
    &=p+p\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(s-ps)^{k}\\
    &=p+p\frac{s-ps}{1-(s-ps)}\\
    &=...=\frac{p}{1-s+ps}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

The correct answer is $\frac{ps}{1-s+ps}$. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write $p_X(k) = p(1 - p)^k  \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, k = 0, 1,2, ...$,

you are implying $X$ takes the value $0$ with probability $p$, which is wrong. A geometric RV only takes integer values $ \geq 1$.

Just work with $$p_X(k) = \begin{cases}
p(1 - p)^{k-1} & k=1,2,...\\
0 & \text{ otherwise }
\end{cases}$$

And you will be fine.

Comment: I suspect "wrong" is a little strong here as there are at least two common forms of the geometric distribution (plus another two which swap $p$ and $1-p$).  So "different" might be more helpful

Answer (score 2):

The two pmfs you provide are not for equivalent random variables because they have different supports. Thus they do not have the same pgf. You found the pgf for the geometric random variable that starts at $0$, and the one you're looking for is for the one that starts at $1$.